# A simple problem over reflection of point about a line

Tags: analytic-geometry

My question is extremely dull, so please don't bother: I want to have an explicit expression for the reflection of a point $(p,q)$ about a line $y=mx$, in terms of coefficients $p$,$q$ and $m$. But I am unable to get it. (Atleast no textbook or website mentions it to my reach). Please help.

Comment: "Please don't bother"? To answer your question?

Comment: @Shubham Johri , I know that my question is a lack of mind and totally dull , and I fear that it may be put on hold or closed by the community , but the concept of reflection is quite new to me and I really don't know a bit about it.

Comment: It's okay I guess. Nobody is at the same level and this website is meant for general consumption. All you have to do is convince us that you have genuinely tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the image of $(p,q)$ be $(a,b)$.

[image: Sample Graph]

Since the line joining these two points is orthogonal to $y=mx$, its slope $=\frac{b-q}{a-p}=-1/m$. Further, the midpoint of the line segment joining these two points lies on $y=mx\implies \frac{b+q}2=m\cdot\frac{a+p}2$. Solve these two equations to get $(a,b)=(\frac{2mq-p(m^2-1)}{m^2+1},\frac{2mp+q(m^2-1)}{m^2+1})$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple derivation using complex numbers.

Let $\alpha$ be the angle the line forms with the positive $x$-semiaxis, so $m=\tan\alpha$; we can choose $-\pi/2<\alpha<\pi/2$.

We can find the point corresponding to $(p,q)$ in three steps:

1. rotate the point around the origin by the angle $-\alpha$;
2. get the reflection of the point about the $x$-axis;
3. rotate the point around the origin by the angle $\alpha$.

If we identify $(p,q)$ with $z=p+iq$ and consider $u=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha$, then the three operations above are

1. multiply $z$ by $u^{-1}=\bar{u}$;
2. get the conjugate;
3. multiply by $u$.

The bar denotes conjugation.

Thus the corresponding point is
$$
\overline{(z\bar{u})}u=\bar{z}uu=u^2\bar{z}
$$
Now it's just a matter of separating the real and imaginary parts. Note that
$$
u^2=\cos2\alpha+i\sin2\alpha
$$
so we have
$$
u^2\bar{z}=(\cos2\alpha+i\sin2\alpha)(p-iq)=(p\cos2\alpha+q\sin2\alpha)+i(p\sin2\alpha-q\cos2\alpha)
$$
Taking into account that
$$
\cos2\alpha=\frac{1-\tan^2\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}=\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2},\qquad
\sin2\alpha=\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}=\frac{2m}{1+m^2}
$$
we have
$$
(p,q)\mapsto\left(\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2}p+\frac{2m}{1+m^2}q,\frac{2m}{1+m^2}p-\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2}q\right)
$$
In matrix form, identifying a point with a column vector, the transformation is
$$
\begin{bmatrix} p \\ q \end{bmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{1-m^2}{1+m^2} & \dfrac{2m}{1+m^2} \\
\dfrac{2m}{1+m^2} & -\dfrac{1-m^2}{1+m^2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} p \\ q \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos2\alpha & \sin2\alpha \\
\sin2\alpha & -\cos2\alpha
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} p \\ q \end{bmatrix}
$$
Note that the trigonometric representation is also valid for any angle, including $\pi/2$.